# Header centered on desktop, but not mobile?

Tags: html, css, mobile, center, centering

I have a banner image with a header overlaying it. When viewed on desktop, the header is both vertically and horizontally aligned. However, using a mobile device makes it so that it is horizontally center, but not vertically. 
(I know it's best to use a style sheet, but for the time being, I have he CSS in-line. I'll fix it eventually. 
CSS/HTML:

```
<div class="banner-b" style="position: relative; height: 300px; background: url(http://s6.postimg.org/j8n8hawrl/Flower.png) center no-repeat; background-size: cover; top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;">
                <div class="overlay-b" style="position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; background: url(http://s6.postimg.org/6sqink3fl/Flower_Blur.png) center no-repeat; background-size: cover; z-index: 0; opacity: 0;"></div>
                <div class="content-b" style="margin: 0px auto; z-index: 10; text-align: center; position: relative; top: 50%; transform: translateY(-50%); font-size: 50px;">
                    <hgroup style="margin: 0px auto; display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle; textalign: center; position: relative; top: 0%; left: 0%; color: #fff; border: 5px solid #fff; padding: 40px; background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .7); z-index: -100;">
                         <h1 style="margin: 0px auto; color: white;">Wolf Valley</h1>

                    </hgroup>
                </div>
            </div>
```

site: [wolfvalley.freeforums.net](http://wolfvalley.freeforums.net) 
[image: Mobile]

Answer (score 1):

It's your browser: the css `transform` property needs a fix for Safari. Try:

```
 <div class="content-b" style="margin: 0px auto; z-index: 10; text-align: center; position: relative; top: 50%; transform: translateY(-50%); -webkit-tranform: translateY(-50%); -moz-transform: translateY(-50%); font-size: 50px;">
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not the complete answer i am providing to you. 
You will have to set viewport to view your page correctly in handheld devices.

e.g., `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">` in your head tag of html.

Also you will have to adjust css accordingly to the device you want to view your page by adding media query in css.

e.g.,

```
@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
        h1 {
           text-align: center;
        }
      }

    @media screen and (min-width:450px){
        h1 {
            text-align: center;
        }

        h2 {
            text-align: left;
        }
    }
```

NOTE: This is just what i thought will look. You will have to alter the css according to the way you want to display things on different devices.

Comment: I added this, and it definitely did something, though, not center the header. It just squashed all of the site's contents together.

Comment: Yes so that you do not have to scroll on hand held device. But you will have to add media queries so that your image fits properly on mobile devices. Also you will have to use flex-wrap : wrap css throughout your css. I guess a lot of work is pending

Comment: Hmm.. Is there anyway I could rig it without doing so much?  I'm sure there has to be something

Comment: Thats the only way i know how to do it. But as i see your site is looking good on different mobiles by adding viewport.

Comment: Alright, well, thanks for the help! It definitely makes the problem easier to analyze.